# How to search for exact matches of single-word video titles?

Tags: youtube, search

I would like to search for videos on YouTube whose title matches a single-word query.

For example, if I search for titles containing the word "verb",  I only want YouTube to return results where the complete video title is "verb".

I have tried searching using `intitle:verb` but it returns videos with other words in the title in addition to "verb".

I searched online but was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe as of today (25 July 2022), neither Google search, neither YouTube have a way to search for exact titles.

Both services have quite sophisticated search algorithm, but none of them even tries to offer a solution with that level of flexibility.